# PDF File - Check for Update with Java?

Tags: java

I want to post some instructional PDF files to my website for my customers to download.  From time to time these PDF files will be updated with new content and I want my customers to have the latest version of these PDF files.

Because Java is supported in Acrobat PDF, is there a way in Java to check my site to see if a newer version of the PDF exists when it is opened and if so, notify the user and give them the option to download the latest version?

It would probably be best if the script would only run every 4th or 5th time the PDF is opened so as not to be overly annoying to the customer.

As I am not familiar with the Java language, if someone knows how to make this work, a full script would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Jon :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to download the file, wrap into an object of type [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and then check the result of the `lastModified()` method to determine if the file was changed since you last checked. Something like:

```
long lastModified = 0;
loop {
    // download file
    File file = new File("file_path");
    long modified = file.lastModified(); 
    if(modified > lastModified) {
        // notify users 
        lastModified = modified;
    }
    // wait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know only, that with Adobe JS one can in a one-liner call a SOAP web service, say fetching a date & time. You could then alter the content, adding a link for an update.